# jQuery tmpl call another template from template

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am using Knockout with jQuery tmpl.

How can I pass some data inside a template "filter-string" if I call it like that:

```
{{tmpl() '#filter-string'}}
```

My template looks like that:

```
<script type="text/html" id="filter-string">
   <input type="text" data-bind="value: $data" />
</script>
```

How can I apply jquery date picker on textbox after template rendered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [knockout.js tutorial](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), here's how you pass the data into template when you do your binding:

```
<div data-bind="template: { name: 'person-template', data: buyer }"></div>
```

provide more code if that's not what you're after